# Error recording audio using pyaudio - IOError: [Errno -9997]

Tags: python, áudio

Estou tentando gravar um audio a partir de um script que desenvolvi com o python usando pyaudio mas estou me deparando com um erro estranho, segue abaixo o script que foi salvo com o nome rec.py:

```
import pyaudio
import wave
import sys

CHUNK = 1024
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 1
RATE = 16000
RECORD_SECONDS = int(sys.argv[2])
WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME = sys.argv[1]

#RECORD_SECONDS = 7
#WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME = "output.wav"
print RECORD_SECONDS
print WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

stream = p.open(format=FORMAT,
                channels=CHANNELS,
                rate=RATE,
                input=True,
                frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)

print("* recording")

frames = []

for i in range(0, int(RATE / CHUNK * RECORD_SECONDS)):
    data = stream.read(CHUNK)
    frames.append(data)

print("* done recording")

stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
p.terminate()

wf = wave.open(WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME, 'wb')
wf.setnchannels(CHANNELS)
wf.setsampwidth(p.get_sample_size(FORMAT))
wf.setframerate(RATE)
wf.writeframes(b''.join(frames))
wf.close()
```

O script funciona bem, mas quando eu tento rodar com o "sudo" me da o erro abaixo:

sudo python rec.py "test.mp3" 5

```
Expression 'PaAlsaStream_Configure( stream, inputParameters, outputParameters, sampleRate, framesPerBuffer, &inputLatency, &outputLatency, &hostBufferSizeMode )' 
failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 2843
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "rec.py", line 26, in <module>
    frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyaudio.py", line 750, in open
    stream = Stream(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyaudio.py", line 441, in __init__
    self._stream = pa.open(**arguments)
IOError: [Errno -9997] Invalid sample rate
```

Se eu rodo sem o "sudo" funciona tudo bem.

Até aqui tudo bem eu poderia rodar sem o sudo, mas o objetivo desse script é colocar ele para rodar dentro de um bash script como serviço. aparentemente o linux executa os servicos com o "sudo" e o mesmo erro ocorre:

Alguem já enfrentou esse problema? Saberiam me dizer como posso resolver-lo?

Comment: Saudações, ilegnaro. Estamos no [pt.so], então poderia traduzir sua pergunta?

Comment: ops...nao tinha percebido, vou traduzir. obrigado!